Getting 2 Unhandled Runtime Error on the dashboard page of the tutorial of next.js
i am following the tutorial provided on nextjs.org and i am at chapter 7 [https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/fetching-data#fetching-data-for-revenuechart] and am getting these errors:
Unhandled Runtime Error
[ Server ] Error: Error connecting to database: fetch failed

and
Unhandled Runtime Error
[ Server ] Error: Failed to fetch revenue data.

The page.tsx of dashboard is:
import { Card } from '@/app/ui/dashboard/cards';
import RevenueChart from '@/app/ui/dashboard/revenue-chart';
import LatestInvoices from '@/app/ui/dashboard/latest-invoices';
import { lusitana } from '@/app/ui/fonts';
import { fetchRevenue } from '@/app/lib/data';

export default async function Page() {
    const revenue = await fetchRevenue();
  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className={`${lusitana.className} mb-4 text-xl md:text-2xl`}>
        Dashboard
      </h1>
      <div className="grid gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
        {/* <Card title="Collected" value={totalPaidInvoices} type="collected" /> */}
        {/* <Card title="Pending" value={totalPendingInvoices} type="pending" /> */}
        {/* <Card title="Total Invoices" value={numberOfInvoices} type="invoices" /> */}
        {/* <Card
          title="Total Customers"
          value={numberOfCustomers}
          type="customers"
        /> */}
      </div>
      <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-8">
        <RevenueChart revenue={revenue}  />
        {/* <LatestInvoices latestInvoices={latestInvoices} /> */}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

Please help

this is clear. you are not connected to database.
